# Finding Cousins in binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

In a binary tree two nodes are cousins if they are on same level and they have different parent.

For this in a binary search tree, I associated with every key a level using a tree map and also associated with every key a parent using a tree map. Then i invoke BFS on root which sets the levels of various keys.

But my isCousins function is giving false even for nodes that are cousins.For example in the binary tree i have created in my code, 12 and 50 are cousins but still it is printing false.

Here is my source code.

```
import java.util.*;
class BST
{
 Node root;
 LinkedList<Node> q=new LinkedList<Node>();
 TreeMap<Integer,Integer> level=new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>(); 
 TreeMap<Integer,Node> parent=new TreeMap<Integer,Node>(); 
 Node insert(Node x,int key)
 {
     if(x==null)
     {
         parent.put(key,null);
         return new Node(key,null,null,null);
     }
     else if(x.key<key)
     {
         x.right=insert(x.right,key);
         x.right.parent=x;
         parent.put(key,x.right.parent);
         return x;
     }
     else if(x.key>key)
     {
         x.left=insert(x.left,key);         
         x.left.parent=x;
         parent.put(key,x.left.parent);
         return x;
     }
     else { x.key=key; return x;}
 }
 public void BFS(Node r)
 {
     if(r==null)
      return;
     if(r.parent==null)
      level.put(r.key,0);
     else level.put(r.key,level.get(r.parent.key)+1);     
     q.add(r);

     while(q.size()!=0)
     {
        Node n=q.poll();
        BFS(n.left);
        BFS(n.right);
     }
 } 
public boolean isCousins(int a,int b)
{
 BFS(root);
 if(level.get(a)==level.get(b)&&parent.get(a)!=parent.get(b))
  return true;
 else return false;
}
public static void main(String []args)
 {
     BST tree1=new BST();
     tree1.root=null;
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,15);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,66);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,5);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,3);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,12);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,75);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,50);     
     System.out.println(tree1.isCousins(12,50));
 }
} 
class Node
{
 Node left,right,parent;
 int key;
 int level;
 Node(int k,Node l,Node r,Node p)
 {
     key=k;
     left=l;
     right=r;
     parent=p;
 }
}
```

Comment: I have been testing it using: https://ideone.com/RRvSpf

It seems to be saying that they are on the same level, but it thinks they have the same parent (12, 50)

Comment: Thanks man! found the mistake.

Comment: Mind posting it for others / my curiosity?

Comment: Nodes are cousins if their parents have the same parent. Getting rid of this level business would clean up your code considerably.

Comment: @erickson But what about this http://www.crazyforcode.com/tree/

Comment: There's no map from node to level there. And those nodes link from parent to child. You are tracking the link backward from child to parent, so why not make use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of Patrick Murphy, wrong output was coming due to small mistake which i easily corrected using following contion:

if(parent.get(key)==null)

The correct code is:

```
import java.util.*;
class BST
{
 Node root;
 LinkedList<Node> q=new LinkedList<Node>();
 TreeMap<Integer,Integer> level=new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>(); 
 TreeMap<Integer,Node> parent=new TreeMap<Integer,Node>(); 
 Node insert(Node x,int key)
 {
     if(x==null)
     {
         parent.put(key,null);
         return new Node(key,null,null,null);
     }
     else if(x.key<key)
     {
         x.right=insert(x.right,key);
         x.right.parent=x;
         if(parent.get(key)==null)
         parent.put(key,x);
         return x;
     }
     else if(x.key>key)
     {
         x.left=insert(x.left,key);         
         x.left.parent=x;
         if(parent.get(key)==null)
         parent.put(key,x);
         return x;
     }
     else { x.key=key; return x;}
 }
 public void BFS(Node r)
 {
     if(r==null)
      return;
     if(r.parent==null)
      level.put(r.key,0);
     else level.put(r.key,level.get(r.parent.key)+1);     
     q.add(r);

     while(q.size()!=0)
     {
        Node n=q.poll();
        BFS(n.left);
        BFS(n.right);
     }
 }
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
     BST tree1=new BST();
     tree1.root=null;
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,15);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,66);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,5);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,3);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,12);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,75);
     tree1.root=tree1.insert(tree1.root,50);
     System.out.println(tree1.isCousins(66,75));
}
public boolean isCousins(int a,int b)
{
 BFS(root);
 if(level.get(a)==level.get(b)&&parent.get(a)!=parent.get(b))
  return true;
 else return false;
}
} 
class Node
{
 Node left,right,parent;
 int key;
 int level;
 Node(int k,Node l,Node r,Node p)
 {
     key=k;
     left=l;
     right=r;
     parent=p;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Node is not a primitive type, so you can't have code that reads:

```
parent.get(a)!=parent.get(b);
```

Using primitive operators to compare non-primitive types just compares the object references, not the actual contents of the objects themselves. Instead, write:

```
!parent.get(a).equals(parent.get(b));
```

Since the value in your TreeMap level is an Integer and not an int, you shouldn't compare them with ==. Instead, use the .equals() method again.

```
level.get(a).equals(level.get(b));
```

Also,

```
level.get(a).equals(level.get(b))&&!parent.get(a).equals(parent.get(b));
```

is a boolean statement, so you could just put

```
return level.get(a).equals(level.get(b))&&!parent.get(a).equals(parent.get(b));
```

instead of

```
if(level.get(a).equals(level.get(b))&&!parent.get(a).equals(parent.get(b)))
   return true;
return false;
```